# Has nvim ever worked on windows for anyone?

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows

Neovim from the command line works great in Linux, and I have been using it as a drop in replacement for vim.

However, I am forced to work with windows (7) at my workplace. I am using vim8 which lacks some of my favourite features and also comes out as unreliable with some of the modern plugins.

I have tried to install neovim several times on my windows machine and have never got the qt gui to work. I have tried to install by download and by chocolatey. I have also tried installing on windows 10. Neovim has never worked for me, and I always get a small window with the message that "Neovim is taking too long to respond".

I am just wondering, is it just me who is incompetent or does it betray everyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it installed on my Win10 using scoop. Neovim-qt works better than nvim on cmd but still vim8 is more reliable.

Issue with "Neovim is taking too long to respond" happens when you have smth wrong in your init.vim. Console nvim shows the error and you can continue, neovim-qt on the other hand just hangs.

For example, if I add the `messssagae "hello world"` as the first line of `init.vim` I got the behaviour you describe.

I suggest to try run nvim using cmd first, fix the errors that it shows and then try neovim-qt.

I personally like the idea of neovim, but on windows still use vim8 most of the time.

Comment: Is there a nvim for command line how do you get that to work? Some of the plugin developers are becoming indifferent towards vim8, esp on windows. How do you feel about that?

Comment: well, nvim for command line is just nvim.exe. I do install it from scoop and then just `nvim` on cmd line and it is there.

Comment: As for plugin developers that indifferent towards vim8, I don't see it much. There are some, but I don't feel I badly need their plugins.

Comment: As it turns out, it was my incompetence ... partly. I had my vim8 rc file sourced in init.vim and was expecting it to work like it does for nvim in linux. The qt gui reports the error and get stuck like you said, however, the console vim didn't continue unlike what you said, so I thought it was just supposed to start an nvim server or something. That said there are still enough quirks to keep us stuck with no choice but vim 8.

Comment: @LazyLeopard, actually you're right, console nvim get stuck for me too. But at least  you can see there are errors.